# How do I view the full text of truncated Driven Property "Tips" (Warnings, etc)?

Tags: drivers

I can't read the Tip (nor of the Warning) in this Driven Property box, and I don't seem to be able to resize it. How can I view the full text of the Tip?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose *Open Drivers Editor* from the context menu:
[image: context menu]

There you can resize the sidebar panel and read the messages:
[image: driver editor]

Comment: Hm -- thanks. I guess I mischaracterized my problem, then; I had actually tried clicking "Show in Drivers Editor" (different prompt due to my using 2.83, I assume), expecting that might be the normal way to view long messages, but the Driver isn't displayed inside the Drivers editor. I'll amend this question and accept your answer, and maybe post the non-appearing Driver as a separate question.

Comment: Off the top of my head: Have you selected the node the driver belongs to, before right-clicking on the value field to navigate to the driver?

Comment: Useful tip no doubt, but I hoped for a solution to a more general problem, for all Blender tooltips. Investigated it a while ago and couldn't find a solution. It doesn't help that Blender doesn't use standard OS API to create its controls (I guess as a tangential consequence, it also doesn't support accessibility features, not sure if it matters in 3D software), so I failed to hack the problem with Autohotkey on Windows...